# Launch Thickbox onload Instead Of click

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I want to launch a jquery thickbox `onload` instead of click. for this I use the code below.

```
<script language="javascript">
    tb_show("HAI","#TB_inline?height=240&amp;width=405&amp;inlineId=hiddenModalContent&amp;modal=true",null);
</script>
```

Actual link is

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=240&amp;width=405&amp;inlineId=hiddenModalContent&
amp;modal=true" class="thickbox">Change Name</a>
```

When I click the above link..thick box appears..

but on body onload thick box is not appearing..

Please help regarding this..

Thanks in advance...

regards
Yen

Answer (score 6):

Your code should work. Maybe try putting it in a call to jQuery's document.ready
e.g.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        tb_show("HAI","#TB_inline?height=240&amp;width=405&amp;inlineId=hiddenModalContent&amp;modal=true",null);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Dear, I am applying your suggested solution, but on load screen dim but not show the page!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Please use window instead of document. I too tried based on the way then it works.

Comment: note that sometimes you need to use $(window).load for this to work properly - for instance when trying to open an inline modal on wp-admin, document.ready didn't cut it.

Comment: If neither $(document) nor $(window) are working, I found that sometimes the page needs a second or two to finish loading completely before calling the thickbox even when telling jQuery to wait until the document is ready. Strange but true. Here's an example: `$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(function() {tb_show('HAI', '#TB_inline?height=240&width=405&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true',null);}, 1000);`

Answer (score 3):

Uffff!!! Finally I have sorted it out, I think your div content is something like
`<div id="hiddenModalContent" style="display:none">My Content</div>`
Try this instead of the above one 
`<div id="hiddenModalContent" style="display:none"><div>My Content</div></div>`
This should fix the problem. Please note that you have to encapsulate the content in "hiddenModalContent" by an HTMl element e.g. `<div>...</div><p>...</p>` etc.

Because in thickbox.js file they have used .children() not .html(). This is the reason why we have to encapsulate the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your anchor link somewhere on the page, you can do something like:

```
<script>
$.ready( function() {
    $("#thickBoxLink").trigger("click");
}
</script>

<html>
<body>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=240&amp;width=405&amp;inlineId=hiddenModalContent&amp;modal=true" id="thickBoxLink" class="thickbox">Change Name</a>
</body>
</html>
```

That should simulate clicking on the link and open up the thickbox for you when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same solution that Matt Frear suggested that you can copy and paste to test. I changed the thickbox parameters but you can change it as you want.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox-compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
   tb_show('HAI','http://microsoft.com?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=350&width=520');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```